# How to set a task variable from a remote powershell script?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-release-task

From a release definition,

When I execute the following powershell script with the powershell task, it works 
successfully and I can retrieve the value from the following tasks in the release definition :

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=sslThumbprint]toto"
```

When I execute the exact same script thanks to the "Powershell on target machine task", I don't get any value.

How can I set a variable from a powershell script that do not execute on the agent machine ?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

This can only be done in case of hosted agents. If you are using hosted agents then only you will be able to run the commands on the agent's machine.

Microsoft as of now provides no feature for doing this.